# MochaJS sending HTTP Request in after hook

Tags: node.js, http, mocha.js

I'm trying to send a http delete request to my web server in Mocha's after hook. Here's the relevant code:

```
after(function() {
    console.log('here at after');
    request.del('http://localhost:3000/api/deleteAllTasks', function(req, res) {
        console.log(req);
    });
});
```

The problem is that the delete endpoint is never being hit. It console.logs "here at after" but never console.logs the request in the callback for request.del. I'm not sure what is causing this; I know the endpoint works as I've sent curl requests to it successfully. Anyone have any ideas? Ultimately, I want this endpoint to clear the DB after this particular test suite runs.

Answer (score 0):

Betting that your script is ending before the asynchronous request is actually made.  Try changing your `after(function() {...` to include the "done" parameter like `after(function(done) {...` and calling `done()` within the inner callback.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please mark the answer as correct to help the next person!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a new after block that will make your test work. leetibbett is completely correct.

```
after(function(done) {
    console.log('here at after');
    request.del('http://localhost:3000/api/deleteAllTasks', function(err, res) {
        console.log(res);
        done();
    });
});
```